# Menu em forma de aba inferior

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber qual é a forma de criar um menu como este em uma linha da tabela?

Ou também como é o nome para eu procurar...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você se refere aos 3 botões?

Comment: Sim Papa Charlie

Comment: Ficarei muito grato

Comment: Atualizei o JS e o jsfiddle, dê uma olhada

Comment: Tentei fazer um título melhor pro Google, não tenho certeza se "aba" é a melhor palavra, talvez sim (?) O que acham? @PapaCharlie / Rod

Comment: "sobreposição de elementos", "botões flutuantes", "mouse e ativação de botões"... Não estou muito criativo hoje :) Algum serviu?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### JS e jsfiddle atualizados

Fiz um exemplo online no [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zyjm3mor/1/).
Suponho que você pretenda ter ações, e isso é uma listagem de registros, então fiz uma referencia da ID da DIV com o ID do registro. Com ele você passa para o JS efetuar as ações.

<sub>**HTML**</sub>

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="elemento" id="1">Rod</div>
</div>

<div class="group">
    <div class="elemento" id="2">Papa Charlie</div>
</div>
```

<sub>**JS**</sub>

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.group').bind('mouseenter', function() {
        var html = '<div id="botoes"><b>Botão 1</b>, <b>Botão 2</b>, <b>Botão 3</b></div>';
        $(this).closest('div').append(html).css( "background", "#FFFFCC" )
        $('#botoes').show();
    });

    $('.group').bind('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).css( "background", "#ffffff" )
        $('#botoes').remove();
    });

});
```

<sub>**CSS**</sub>

```
*{font-family:"Tahoma", "Arial", sans-serif; font-size:12px}
.elemento{border:#f3f3f3 solid 1px; padding:5px; margin:2px}
#botoes{background:#FFFFCC; border:#f3f3f3 solid 1px; padding:5px; margin:2px 2px 2px 100px; width:170px; margin-top:-4px; border-top:none; display:none; position:absolute; text-align:center}
```

Comment: Cara muito bom.

Comment: Estou tentando ajustar uns detalhes

Comment: Obrigado Papa Charlie, acho que entendi a base, agora tento me virar sozinho, foi de grande ajuda amigo :)

Comment: Bacana, de qualquer forma eu dou uma atualizada se der :)

Comment: Neste caso como a tabela será gerada automaticamente o melhor seria fazer com div's escondidos e dar um .show() quando se desse hover.

Comment: O @Kazzkiq abordou o exemplo muito bem. São 2 formas diferentes de fazer.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer esta funcionalidade dos botões direto no CSS:

```
/* Div dentro da sua <td>, contendo os botões */
.embrulho{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}    
tr:hover .embrulho{
    overflow:visible;
}

/* div que vai aparecer com os botões dentro da .embrulho */
.botoes{
    position:absolute;
}
```

Exemplo do funcionamento: **[`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/56czfoxc/)**

Para conseguir disparar eventos nos botões você pode criar um atributo *(como na resposta do @PapaCharlie)* em cada um dos botões e depois puxar eles com JavaScript:

```
// pode ser usado com onclick="retornaId(this)", ou com um listener, etc.
function retornaId(el){
    return el.getAttribute('data-id');
}
```

Exemplo completo: **[`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/wnmdb0au/)**

Comment: Ficou show o código!!!